# Extracting top subreddits from an HTML table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, reddit

I'm scraping a table and am trying to get nested td tags down the tbody tree but the code seems kind of verbose.  Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

```
def get_top_subreddits(url):

    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

    body = soup.find_all('tbody')

    top_subreddits = []
    for i in body:
        trs = i.find_all('tr')
        for tr in trs:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in tds:
                texts = td.get_text()
                if '/r/' in texts:
                    top_subreddits.append(texts)
    return top_subreddits
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Are there any `<td>` that appear outside a `<tr>` in a `<tbody>`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a more concise way to do it - using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and a list comprehension:

```
top_subreddits = [
    td.get_text()
    for td in soup.select("tbody tr td")
    if '/r/' in td.text
]
```

`tbody tr td` would locate all `td` elements under `tr` elements which are under `tbody`.

I don't really like getting texts of `td` elements twice here, there is possibly a way to filter the desired information directly. E.g. if you were up to the subreddit links, we could've applied the `/r/` check inside a selector:

```
top_subreddits = [
    a.get_text()
    for a in soup.select('tbody tr td a[href^="/r/"]')
]
```

`^=` here means "starts with".